# how to insert first row value static when the onCreate() method will call and other will be dynamic on click button in a database?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I check if customer `index=0` then inserting the data on `OnCREATE` method and else part inserting the data on click button.

```java
if (C_Id==0){
    helper.CustomerAdd(new CustomerModel("developer","test","test@gmail.com","9874643212","test",null,"abc road","gurgaon","india",null));
}

public int CustomerAdd(CustomerModel fm){
    int cust_id=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put( C_NAME, fm.getC_name() );
    cv.put( C_NO, fm.getC_phone() );
    cv.put( C_EMAIL, fm.getC_email() );
    cv.put( BILL_NAME, fm.getC_bill_name() );
    cv.put( GST_NO, fm.getGst_no() );
    cv.put( C_ADDRESS, fm.getC_address() );
    cv.put( CITY, fm.getC_city() );
    cv.put( Country, fm.getC_country() );
    cv.put( DESCRIPTION, fm.getDescription() );
    cv.put( JOB_Tittle, fm.getJob_title());
    SimpleDateFormat sdfdndj = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yy" );
    String Timedatanew = sdfdndj.format( new java.util.Date() );
    cv.put( Created_date, Timedatanew );
    try{
        db.insert( CUSTOMER_TABLE, null, cv );
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery( "Select C_ID from CUSTOMER Order by C_ID DESC limit 1",null);
        if (cursor.moveToLast()){
            cust_id= cursor.getInt( 0 );
        }else {
            cust_id=0;
        }
    }
```

**I tried** like this but don't know how to add data on the first row.
any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend usage of "Room" from android architecture component. its a better option as it will abstract many small decision which are gracefully handled by that ORM

Answer (score 1):

Your issue could be that you begin a transaction but don't commit ([setTransactionSuccessful](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#setTransactionSuccessful())) and end the transaction.

However, for a single action such as inserting a row then there is no need to begin/commit/end as being a single action it will be it's own transaction.

As such, you could just remove the line `db.beginTransaction();`

---

If your issue is how to add a row to the CUSTOMER table, if there are no rows, in the onCreate method of an activity, then you could code and call the following method (this assumes that the CustomerAdd method is in a class named **MyDatabaseHelper**, therefore you may need to change accordingly)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    helper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
    addFirstCustomerIfNone(); //<<<<<<<<<<
}

private void addFirstCustomerIfNone() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,"CUSTOMER") < 1) {
        if (helper.CustomerAdd(new CustomerModel("developer","test","test@gmail.com","9874643212","test",null,"abc road","gurgaon","india",null)) ==0) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Customer Added Successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Customer was not added.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Thus when the activity is started and the onCreate method is invoked **helper** (an instance of the database helper class) is instantiated and then the **addFirstCustomerIfNone** method is called.

The **addFirstCustomerIfNone** method checks to see if the CUSTOMER table has any rows, if not then the first row is added. If rows already exists then nothing is added.

- **Note** the above is based upon the available information and makes some assumptions and may therefore not cater for all circumstance.

Comment: @rachna, that's good, If you believe that the answer helper you resolve the issue, you should tick the answer to show that it answered the question.